# Keras model not using GPU when using particular OpenCV functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras

When I am training my Unet model from the segmentation_models library using a custom generator with a particular set of augmentations the Kaggle Metrics shows 100% GPU usage. However, if I add the following lines of code the GPU usage drops to 0% sometimes reaching 4-6%.

Code added:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor( img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur( gray, (9,9), 0 )
_,thresh_img = cv2.threshold( blurred, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask  = cv2.dilate( thresh_img, None, iterations=4 )
img = cv2.inpaint( img, mask,10,cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

Is there any reason the above code is preventing the model to train using the GPU? Are there any workarounds to this problem?

Edit:
Also of the above functions, I am using `cv2.cvtColor`, `cv2.GaussianBlur`, and `cv2.threshold` elsewhere during image augmentation, and the GPU usage remains at 100%. My guess is `cv2.dilate` or `cv2.inpaint` is causing the problem, but I am not sure why.

Code inside the generator:

```
def train_generator():
    while True:
        rng_state = np.random.get_state()
        np.random.shuffle(X_train)
        np.random.set_state(rng_state)
        np.random.shuffle(Y_train)
        for start in range(0, nb_train_samples, batch_size):
            x_batch = []
            y_batch = []
            end = min(start + batch_size, nb_train_samples)
            for img_path in range(start, end):
                
                img = cv2.imread(dir_train + X_train[img_path])
                img = cv2.resize(img, (width, height))
                
                gray = cv2.cvtColor( img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
                blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur( gray, (9,9), 0 )
                _,thresh_img = cv2.threshold( blurred, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
                mask  = cv2.dilate( thresh_img, None, iterations=4 )
                img = cv2.inpaint( img, mask,10,cv2.INPAINT_NS)
                
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
                image = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(0,0),3)
                cv2.addWeighted(image, 0.5, img, 0.5, 0, img)
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                img = img.reshape((height,width,1))
                image = None
                
                img = myPreproc(img)
                img = np.float32(img) / 255
                x_batch.append(img)
                
                lbl = np.load(dir_train + Y_train[img_path])
                lbl = cv2.resize(lbl, (width, height))
                seg = np.zeros((  height , width  , nc ))
                for c in range(nc):
                    seg[:, :, c] = (lbl==c).astype(int)
                label = seg
                lbl = None
                label = lblProc(label)
                y_batch.append(label)
            
            yield (np.array(x_batch), np.array(y_batch))
```

GPU usage sample picture:
[image: GPU usage]

Comment: Did your opencv package compile for GPU?

Comment: Yes, I am using multiple other OpenCV functions in my image augmentation function and the GPU usage is 100%. It is only when the above block of code is added does the usage becomes 0.

Comment: Where is this block of code being added? Without actual code for context there is not much we can say.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have modified the question. Hope it provides the required context.

Comment: Pleased do not add code as images, but as text.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy replaced the image with code.